# Using Alter Field tool of ArcGIS Desktop on shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes

According the [ArcGIS 10.2.2 help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000) this should work:

```
inZoneData = sys.argv[1] # This is a shapefile
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(inZoneData) 
    for field in fieldList:
        if field.name.upper() == 'STATUS':  # rename status
            arcpy.AlterField_management(inZoneData, field, 'status')
```

but it does not.  What I get is invalid parameter.  If I try this:

```
for field in arcpy.ListFields(inZoneData):
    if field.name() == 'STATUS':  # rename status
        arcpy.AlterField_management(inZoneData, 'STATUS', 'status')
```

I get invalid unicode error.  I understand that error at least.

Can anyone shine some light on how AlterField actually works?

I've tried several other things but cannot get this tool working.

Is it a shapefile bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug because, as [@Paul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109905/using-alter-field-tool-of-arcgis-for-desktop-on-shapefile/109977#comment154742_109905) and [@Branco](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109905/using-alter-field-tool-of-arcgis-for-desktop-on-shapefile/109977#comment154750_109905), have said the Alter Field (Data Management) tool documents its scope as (with my bolding):

> This tool provides the ability to rename fields or rename field
>   aliases for any **geodatabase table or feature class**.

If you want to do the same to a shapefile I suggest copying your shapefile into a file geodatabase (or an in_memory workspace) feature class, perform the Alter Field there, and then copy the feature class back to a shapefile.